# Taylor's Theorem: If $x \in [0,1]$ and $n \in \Bbb{N}$, prove the inequality

Tags: real-analysis

> If $x \in [0,1]$ and $n \in \Bbb{N}$, prove that
>
> $$\left|\ln(1+x) - \left(x-\frac{1}{2}x^2 + \frac{1}{3}x^3+ \cdots + \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}x^n\right)\right| < \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$$

---

Now I already have part of the left side of the inequality in polynomial form so I believe I simply need to find a Taylor approximation for $\ln(1+x)$.

I find the following,

- $f(x) = \ln(1+x)$
- $f`(x) = \frac{1}{1+x}$
- $f``(x) = \frac{-1}{(1+x)^2}$

**First Question:** Is there any information telling me to what polynomial degree I need to estimate?

Anyways, I get

$$P_n(0) = 0 + x - \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} - \frac{x^4}{4!} + ... + \frac{(-1)^{n-1}x^n}{n!}$$

**Main Question:** What do I do now? I'm not sure how to combine this result with the already given polynomial. This all assumes my logic is correct as well :/ Thank you in advance!

Comment: A hint:  consider the **remainder**.

Answer (score 2):

You did not go far enough to see that the factorials are not included in the series of ln(1+x).

$$P_n(0) = 0 + x - \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} - \frac{x^4}{4!} + ... + \frac{(-1)^{n-1}x^n}{n!}$$ does not look like ln(1+x) at all.

Regarding the error term, notice that you have an alternating series which converges to ln(1+x). The absolute value of error in a truncated alternating series is less than the absolute value of the next term.

Comment: I don't think your last paragraph answers the question; or, at least you should emphasize that you are assuming that the series converges to the function. The fact that the Taylor series converges is no guarantee that it represents the function. One needs to deal with the remained for that.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Thanks, I edited my  answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

There is an explicit formulation of the remainder in a Taylor approximation, it is:
$$f(x_0+h)-\left(\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{f^{(k)}(x_0)}{k!}h^k \right)=\int_{x_0}^{x_0+h} \frac{f^{(n+1)}(t)}{n!}(x_0+h-t)^ndt$$
(you can prove it by induction using an integration by parts)

Comment: Actually Mohammad Riazi-Kermani answer is way better than mine ^^

Answer (score 1):

I think I have done this
here before,
but, what the heck.

First,
$\ln(1+x)
=\int_0^x \dfrac{dt}{1+t}
$.

Then
$\dfrac{1-t^n}{1-t}
=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} t^k
$
so
$\dfrac{1+(-1)^nt^n}{1+t}
=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^k t^k
$
so that
$\dfrac{1}{1+t}
=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^k t^k-\dfrac{(-1)^nt^n}{1+t}
$.

Integrating from $0$ to $x$,

$\begin{array}\\
\ln(1+x)
&=\int_0^x \dfrac{dt}{1+t}\\
&=\int_0^x\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^k t^k-\dfrac{(-1)^nt^n}{1+t}\right)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^k \int_0^x t^kdt-(-1)^n\int_0^x\dfrac{t^ndt}{1+t}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^k \dfrac{x^{k+1}}{k+1}-(-1)^n\int_0^x\dfrac{t^ndt}{1+t}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^{k-1} \dfrac{x^{k}}{k}+(-1)^{n+1}\int_0^x\dfrac{t^ndt}{1+t}\\
\end{array}
$

so
$\ln(1+x)-\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^{k+1} \dfrac{x^{k}}{k}\right)
=(-1)^{n+1}\int_0^x\dfrac{t^ndt}{1+t}
$
or
$(-1)^{n+1}\left(\ln(1+x)-\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^{k+1} \dfrac{x^{k}}{k}\right)\right)
=\int_0^x\dfrac{t^ndt}{1+t}
$.

Since
$\dfrac1{1+x}
\le \dfrac1{1+t}
\le 1
$
for
$0 \le t \le x$,
$\int_0^x\dfrac{t^ndt}{1+x}
\le \int_0^x\dfrac{t^ndt}{1+t}
\le \int_0^xt^ndt
$
or
$\dfrac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)(1+x)}
\le \int_0^x\dfrac{t^ndt}{1+t}
\le \dfrac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}
$.

Therefore
$\dfrac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)(1+x)}
\le (-1)^{n+1}\left(\ln(1+x)-\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^{k+1} \dfrac{x^{k}}{k}\right)\right)
\le \dfrac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}
$.

Note that
the difference of 
these bounds is
$\dfrac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}-\dfrac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)(1+x)}
=\dfrac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\left(1-\dfrac1{1+x}\right)
=\dfrac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\dfrac{x}{1+x}
=\dfrac{x^{n+2}}{(n+1)(1+x)}
$.

Comment: This is the simpler answer. It doesn't need any knowledge of Taylor series. +1

Comment: I appreciate it but unfortunately I am expected to prove this using Taylor Series. Otherwise I would have just written something like, "I think I should use Taylor Series."